# Which version of git add '%D' as a placeholder of PRETTY FORMATS

Tags: git

Yesterday I ran a script and got something wrong.
Finally I figured out it was caused by a pretty format placeholder - '%D'.
This placeholder hasn't been supported in 1.9.1 yet.

This placeholder has been added at least since 2.2.1, as the doc in 2.2.1 shows it:
http://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

I am curious about which version of git starts to add '%D' as a placeholder of pretty formats?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I checkout the source code of git, and figure out the '%D' placeholder is added since v2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Support for `%D` as a placeholder was added in [this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9271095cc5571e306d709ebf8eb7f0a388254d9d):

> Add a new format specifier, '%D' that is identical in behaviour to '%d',
>   except that it does not include the ' (' prefix or ')' suffix provided
>   by '%d'.

Its first tagged appearance was in v2.2.0-rc0, and it was included in the final release of v2.2.0.